# Listing names to arrays

Tags: python, arrays

```
o = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

I want to be able to show how many 1s, 2s and so on.

For example if there is 6 `1`, it will print `BendingF =  6`. My `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5` are different positions. `1 = BendingF`, `2 = BendingM` , `3 = Twisting`, `4 = Walking`, `5 = Squat`.

I tried

```
##1 = print('Bending Forward')
##2 = print('Bending Midway')
##3 = print('Twisting')
##4 = print('Walking')
##5 = print('Squating')
```

but it will give me error:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: What have you attempted so far to solve this? Have you tried iterating though the list and counting occurrences?

Comment: im using this for machine learning, i tried to do `1 = print('Bending')` but it will tell me literal problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@Amadan* mentioned you can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each occurrence of unique numbers in your array. Then create a dictionary (`labels`) to map your integers to the string values that they would represent:

```
from collections import Counter

o = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]

labels = {
  1: 'Bending Forward',
  2: 'Bending Midway',
  3: 'Twisting',
  4: 'Walking',
  5: 'Squating'
}

count = Counter(o)

for val in count.keys():
  print(labels[val] + " - " + str(count[val]))
```

Outputs

```
 Bending Forward - 9
 Bending Midway - 8
 Twisting - 16
 Walking - 11
 Squating - 8
```

[*Repl link*](https://repl.it/repls/RemorsefulGrandAstrophysics)

Answer (score 1):

```
o = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
print("Bending forward = " + str(o.count(1)))
print("Bending Midway = " + str(o.count(2)))
print("Twisting = " + str(o.count(3)))
print("Walking = " + str(o.count(4)))
print("Squatting = " + str(o.count(5)))
```